# Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object occurs

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put values inside my database but i am not able to achieve through this as i am getting an error constantly .

**ERROR:** *Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object*

**Code:**

```
require '../connect.inc.php';
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(user_email) as usercount FROM registered_users WHERE user_email=$email");     
$user_count = $result->fetch_object()->usercount; //will return 0 if user doesn't exist
```

connect.inc.php connects to the database.Above code throws an error at usercount.

My question is what is am i doing wrong ?

**Note :** It has been marked as duplicate for this question [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) but i don't think it has any problem in quotes and backticks.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB i know that just answer the question if you know what the problem is .

Comment: uh, yes, the problem is quotes. look at the query you're building. do you really think there's a field named `president@whitehouse.gov` in your database? `'president@whitehouse.gov'` and `president@whitehouse.gov` are two entirely different things to an SQL parser...

Comment: oh , could you please tell me the final query that i should use ? @MarcB

Comment: not really. you just need to read the linked duplicate. giving you the answer would be futile, as you'd learn nothing.

Comment: okay i read and tried but still didnt work out @MarcB

Comment: same error as before

Comment: then start writing proper code, and **NOT** assuming nothing would ever fail. `$res = mysqli_query(...); if (!$res) { die(mysqli_error(...)); }`. etc....